# W3C Involvement In Flash & Silverlight

Tags: flash, silverlight, w3c

It seems to me that the key USP of Flash/Silverlight is the ability to provide access (albeit indirectly) to the graphics subsystem of the client, enabling video, smooth transitions and "fancy" visual effects.

This sounds like a good idea, and a natural evolution/extension of HTML. But surely it would be better if someone like the W3C controlled such a technology, rather than Microsoft or Adobe locking users into their "platform".

Has the W3C taken a role in the development of these technologies, and if not, why?

Clarification: I suppose the thrust of my question is - why the W3C is not extending/evolving HTML (or creating another technology) in the Flash/Silverlight "direction" when it seems obvious (to Adobe & MS at least), and an open standard platform would be preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The W3C has no real authority to "take a role" in the development of a proprietary technology. They can only be **given** such a role if the company that owns the technology decides to give it to them, and so far neither Adobe nor Microsoft has done so.

Comment: Thanks for your response; it doesn't really satisfy me though because HTML is developed by the W3C as I understand it, and, I suppose the thrust of my question is - why the W3C is not extending/evolving HTML in the Flash/Silverlight "direction" when it seems obvious (to Adobe & MS at least).

Comment: because flash and Silverlight are "rectangles in your page". The W3C is looking at technologies that can work for the entire page, see mine and bobince's answers.

Comment: @sasserstyl - Because both Adobe and MS are members of the consortium, and they don't want HTML to compete with their proprietary technology. Where'd you get the notion that the W3C is a separate, independent body that dictates standards that others are obligated to follow?

Answer (score 5):

W3C did create another technology, sort of.

SVG is a pretty nice vector graphics standard that, combined with scripting, can do a bunch of things Flash can do, but all in plain XML and JavaScript instead of a lump of binary gunge. It's tricky to call this a Flash replacement as it works so very differently, but it can certainly hit some of the same spots where implemented as first-class browser objects.

There's no video in it, but HTML5 is attacking this (and unlike much of the rest of HTML5, some browsers are actually implementing it).

Of course without IE, these are always going to have limited applicability in the real world.

[Note: in any case, neither Silverlight nor Flash are really totally closed. See eg. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf/ ]

Answer (score 1):

You can and in future will be able to increasingly more of what Flash and Silverlight are capable of using the [Canvas HTML element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_(HTML_element)), [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/) and the new [audio](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/html5/#audio) and [video](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/html5/#video) elements in HTML5.

See this [3D Canvas](http://lbi.lostboys.nl/blog/artikelen/canvas-in-full-3d/) example for what is currently possible.

Comment: Canvas was standardized by the WHATWG, not the W3C but it may become a W3C standard in future.